# Incorrect Django URL pattern match for 2 views with the same URL structure?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I have two url patterns in Django:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<song_name>.+)-(?P<dj_slug>.+)-(?P<song_id>.+)/$', songs.dj_song, name='dj_song'),
    url(r'^(?P<song_name>.+)-(?P<artist_slug>.+)-(?P<song_id>.+)/$', songs.trending_song, name='trending_song'),
)
```

When I visit a URL of the first pattern, it opens it correctly. However if I try and visit a URL of the second pattern, it tries to access the first view again. The variables `song_name`, `dj_slug`, `artist_slug`are strings and `song_id` is an integer.

What should be the URL patterns for such a case with similar URL structure?

Comment: sample urls you tried to access your views with would be useful - maybe then you would realize what was wrong in the first place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both urls use the same regex.  I removed the group names and get:

```
url(r'^(.+)-(.+)-(.+)/$', songs.dj_song, name='dj_song'),
url(r'^(.+)-(.+)-(.+)/$', songs.trending_song, name='trending_song'),
```

Of course django uses the first match.

You should use different urls for different views.  For example add the prefix to the second url:

```
url(r'^trending/(?P<song_name>.+)-(?P<artist_slug>.+)-(?P<song_id>.+)/$',
                                  songs.trending_song, name='trending_song'),
```

Comment: So it isn't possible to use the same URL pattern for 2 different views?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible.  `Yesterday-Beatles-123` - is this the DJ Song of Trending Song? :-)